# Помогите разобраться в коде python

Tags: python-3.x, алгоритм

было задание: вводятся скобки и нужно из функции вернуть True если они расставлены верно и False если нет. 
Пример:

```
{}()[]    = True
([{}])    = True 
{}({})[]  = True
[(])      = False
[({})](]  = False
{)        = False
```

Решение я реализовал 80ти строчками, потом увидел такое решение данного задания

```
def validBraces(s):
  while '{}' in s or '()' in s or '[]' in s:
      s=s.replace('{}','')
      s=s.replace('[]','')
      s=s.replace('()','')
  return s==''
```

Вопрос: почему в строчке while поиск '{}' ищет отдельно **{** и отдельно **}** в строчке, а не **{}** совместно?

Comment: если кому интересно мое решение (https://pastebin.com/LiWaiXVv)

Comment: Что значит «ищет отдельно»? Код вида `'{}' in s` проверяет наличие в строке именно `{}`, а не `{` и не `}`

Comment: все, понял работу кода, он по очереди удаляет каждую пару. Когда дается строка ' ({}) ' он сначала удаляет ' {} ' , строка остается ' () ' и он тоже ее удаляет